# Dynamically adding rows on a webpage and later saving in db

Tags: asp-classic, dynamic-programming, dynamic-data

I have a webpage, classic asp connected to oracle db, herein I will populate a combobox using database, will select a value from the combobox and it.should display 4 fields, I will.enter data in those fields, it will be like a row, then there should be a + button and a new dynamic empty row will appear.with 4 empty fields, will enter some data in them.and if I keep on pressing the +  button rows keep on appearing and in the last when my entries are complete will press save button and all the dynamic rows should get inserted to the database.
Can somebody help me in accomplishing this with example or direction or guidance.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to do it in JavaScript. Have four hidden fields for holding the newly entered values and append values to them after each + button press with some separator ($ for example).
And when user clicks save button you will get all four hidden field values in posted asp file, then just split the values and insert into the database.

And if you want the entered values should persist even though user refreshes the page then use session for storing entered values. I hope this will help you to get started. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, any example to start with , will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Please share some code that you have done so far to get an idea of your way.

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice but to do this in javascript. Create an empty table for holding the rows. Use a library like jQuery to dynamically add a row to the table every time the users clicks "+".
The fields in the new row can have an integer appended or prepended to their name. In javascript you can also fill a hidden form field to keep track of how many rows are on the page currently. For example:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>3           <input type="Hidden" name="quantity[0]" value="3"/></td>
    <td>apples      <input type="Hidden" name="item[0]" value="apples"/></td>
    <td>fruits      <input type="Hidden" name="type[0]" value="fruits"/></td>
    <td>2 days      <input type="Hidden" name="age[0]" value="age"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>7           <input type="Hidden" name="quantity[1]" value="7"/></td>
    <td>carrots     <input type="Hidden" name="item[1]" value="carrots"/></td>
    <td>vegetables  <input type="Hidden" name="type[1]" value="vegetables"/></td>
    <td>3 days      <input type="Hidden" name="age[1]" value="3"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="Hidden" name="itemcount" value="1"/>
```

In ASP you will need to look at the "itemcount" field to see how many items you need to look at.
Then you can create a loop and loop the request.form scope:

```
<% 
    Dim i
    For i = 0 to Cint(request.form("itemcount"))

        response.write(request.form("quantity[" & i & "]"))
        response.write(request.form("item[" & i & "]"))
        response.write(request.form("type[" & i & "]"))
        response.write(request.form("age[" & i & "]"))

    Next 'i
 %>
```

Please note that I didn't test this code, it's just to give you an idea.
You can add the integer to the name of the field any way you like ofcourse (whatever is easy for you to parse), but this way (in brackets) is loosely based on this W3C draft proposal for nesting data in forms:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/